# How do I access only the first key in a Dictionary containing 2 keys?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary with **2 keys** for each distinct value. I need to get a list of only the first key - **{'Stuck', 'on', 'problem'}**.

test_dict = {('Stuck','a') : 1, ('on', 'b') : 2, ('problem','c') : 3}

I've some indexing but nothing seems to work. Also did not find any. specific solution to this online.

Comment: `[key[0] for key in test_dict]`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have two keys for each distinct value: you have **one** key for each distinct value, but the key happens to be a tuple. If you want the first value from each tuple, then you need to:

1. Iterate over the keys, and
2. Extract the first value from each key

```
test_dict = {('Stuck','a') : 1, ('on', 'b') : 2, ('problem','c') : 3}

answer = []
for key in test_dict:
    answer.append(key[0])

print(answer)
```

Or in a more compact form using a list comprehension:

```
test_dict = {('Stuck','a') : 1, ('on', 'b') : 2, ('problem','c') : 3}
answer = [key[0] for key in test_dict.keys()]
print(answer)
```

Comment: small suggestion: `for key in test_dict.keys()` -> `for key in test_dict`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this. I also found another way using un(zip). The order is not preserved but that is not a concern for me.

test_dict = {('Stuck','a') : 1, ('on', 'b') : 2, ('problem','c') : 3}

(p, q) = zip(*set(test_dict))
print(list(p))

Comment: Well, you can definitely simplify this to `zip(*test_dict)`.  Using `set()` will only throw off the order of your keys.